# Rails Routes Resources Member Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have created a nested routes like this

```
  resources :subjects do
    resources :subject_edits do
      member do
        post :vote
      end
    end
  end
```

when I run `rake routes`, I found it exited

```
vote_subject_subject_edit POST   /subjects/:subject_id/subject_edits/:id/vote(.:format) subject_edits#vote
```

but when I use it in my .erb file

```
<%= button_to 'I Agree', :action => vote_subject_subject_edit_path(@subject, @edit) %>
```

I got an error,

> No route matches {:action=>"/subjects/25/subject_edits/1/vote",
>   :subject_id=>"25", :id=>"1", :controller=>"subject_edits"}

what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helper sets url explicitly, so you need:

```
<%= button_to 'I Agree', vote_subject_subject_edit_path(@subject, @edit) %>
```

without passing `:action` option.